# Sometimes clicking won't work for tabbed items on latest Mac OSX

Tags: macos, mouse

Basically, when I go to click on the x in a tab in google chrome (or just the tab in general), click on tabs in my terminal, or any other program, sometimes the left click just won't register at all. It's not specific to a program, just tabs within any program. Well, also sometimes hitting the back arrow or refresh for google chrome doesn't respond either. What I usually do to fix this is click somewhere within the web page again, and then it will respond just fine. However, this happens so often that it is a hassle. It usually has no problem clicking things on webpages or within programs.

I've tried the basics, restarting, reinstalling programs, playing with mouse settings, etc, but nothing has fixed this. This happens both on an external mouse and using the trackpad.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What Chrome version do you have? Does the right click works?

Comment: Latest chrome version, but as I said, this isn't chrome specific. It happens on any software that has tabs.

Comment: @Odymex Have you got a solution for this annoying issue? I have a MacBook-Air.

Comment: Nope... Still having this issue :/